# What's the difference between "currency" and "foreign-exchange" tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

[currency](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currency):

> For questions related to currencies or **foreign exchange** markets. Ideally, this tag should be accompanied by specific currency tags under discussion.

[foreign-exchange](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreign-exchange):

> This tag is to be used for any question related to rates between 2 pairs of **currencies**. If the question is generic, only this tag is sufficient. If its specific for a pair of currencies, ideally both the currency tags should also be used.

I was trying to tag some questions when I couldn't decide on which to use. What is the difference between these two tags?

Comment: "currency" definitely sounds like it has the wrong description.  I would expect it to be about money *within* a country, either the physical money or policies that affect its value or use.